# Show HTML Content with answer in wordpress gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using gravity form in wordpress and I'm facing a problem, I've one HTML content where I write down question `1. Are you presently taking any medications, nutritional supplements or vitamins? Please list (attach sheet if necessary)` and second one is textarea which has label called `Answer:` and third field is textfield which has label called `Not Important`

[image: gravity form question]

So the problem is when I just fill the form and submit it, I get the email every time, below image is email notification which I get every time when ever user submit the form

[image: gravity form]

now as you can see I got answer label every time in my email but doesn't get question with answer in email, I've tried many options in gravity form plugin and I also tried this code

`$gf_pdf_config[] = array(
    'form_id' => 2,
    'notifications' => true,
    'default-show-html' => true,
    'default-show-empty' => true,
    'default-show-page-names' => true,
    'default-show-section-content' => true,
    'template' => 'default-template-two-rows.php',
    'filename' => '{date_mdy}_test-payment-patient-form-justinhealth.pdf'
  );`

in `configuration.php` plugin's file but didn't work for me so is there any solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from this old support thread, adding html to the notification email via merge tags wasn't something they intended or were planning to implement.

https://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/html-block-output-in-email-notifications-and-on-pages

The best bet would be to follow the suggestion by Kevin Flahaut in the thread above and create dummy textarea input fields before each answer textarea, with a default 'answer' which is the text for that question.  Then add a custom css class to all the question textarea fields and apply `display: none` to that class in your CSS.

That way the frontend looks like you want it to with the html as the question, the email notification will contain the question textarea inputs which were hidden on the frontend in the order they should appear in.  No code required.

Comment: No probs at all @user3833682 ! :)